# Adding css animations to item

Tags: css, animation, nativescript

I'm trying to run an animation on an item after a specific trigger.
My idea was to use css-defined keyframe-animations and then add them to the item.
But the way I'm doing it isn't working.

My problem:

If the first click on the button happens, before the intro-animation is done, the following exception occurs:

```
JS: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Animation cancelled.
JS: STACKTRACE:
JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Animation cancelled.
JS:     at resolvePromise (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:496:32)
JS:     at resolvePromise (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:481:18)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:529:18
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:314:38)
JS:     at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:36:41)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:313:43)
JS:     at Zone.runTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:214:48)
JS:     at drainMicroTaskQueue (/data/data/org.nativescript.Animations/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:432:36)
JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: Animation cancelled. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Animation cancelled.
JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Animation cancelled.
```

My css:

```
@keyframes entryFrames {
    from { background-color: blue; }
    to { background-color: yellow; }
}

.entry {
    animation-name: entryFrames;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes triggeredFrames {
    from { background-color: red; }
    to { background-color: green; }
}

.triggered {
    animation-name: triggeredFrames;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

My code:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
import {Label} from "ui/label";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="Press" (tap)="test()"></Button>
    <Label #label1 [text]="'Some'" class="view" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('label1') label1: ElementRef;

    public test() {
        let label1Label = <Label>this.label1.nativeElement;
        label1Label.text="Other";
        //label1Label.className="";
        label1Label.className="view";
    }
}
```

The second missing understanding for me is how to restart an animation.
Restarting works by removing the styleclass and re-adding it, but is this the correct way?

```
// label1Label.className="";
label1Label.className="triggered";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case; I suspect what is happening is that when you change the className you are causing the side effect of the intro animation is then cancelled; as you just removed the class that was running it -- so because it is cancelled it then throws that error.

You might be able to fix this in two possible ways:
Have you considered trying to set the classname to:

```
label1Label.className = "intro triggered";
```

When you want to add a second animation?   I'm not 100% sure this will work; but it is something I would try, as it might allow the first animation to finish while the second one starts.

---

However what should work would be:

```
// Track if an animation is running
var runningAnimation = null;

// Clear our running animation variable so we know no animations are running
function animationDone() {
  runnningAnimation = null;
}

// Call this where you when you want the intro animation done
// Maybe on the pageLoaded or NavigatedTo events
function startIntroAnimation(view) {
   // Set the start color
   label1Label.backgroundColor = new colorModule.Color("blue");
  // start are intro animation
  runningAnimation = view.animate({ backgroundColor: new colorModule.Color("yellow"), duration: 4000 }).then(animationDone).catch(animationDone); 
}

function OnButtonTapped() {
   if (runningAnimation) { 
     runningAnimation.cancel();
   }
   // Set the start color
   label1Label.backgroundColor = new colorModule.Color("red");
   // Animate it to the finish color
   runningAnimation = view.animate({ backgroundColor: new colorModule.Color("green"), duration: 4000 }).then(animationDone).cancel(animationDone);
}
```

By doing it this way you have full control over when to start/cancel animations, and/or you can skip running a animation is own is already in progress.

---

As for your second question; yes if you are just using css animation; then to re-trigger it you need to reset the css properties on it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled explanaition, helps a lot.